# rails has_many :through association doesnt work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a problem with a has_many through association.

I have an account model which has many offices and hotels
account.rb :

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

  # associations
  has_many :partnerships, through: :hotels, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :partnerships, through: :offices, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :hotels, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :hotels, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :offices, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :admin, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "admin_user_id", dependent: :destroy
```

then I have a partnerships table which is a join table between hotels and offices
thus both hotel and office have many partnerships:

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :partnerships
  belongs_to :account
  has_and_belongs_to_many :user

 class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :partnerships
```

and finally my partnership model :

```
class Partnership < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :hotel
  belongs_to :office
```

Yet when I test the association between account and partnership with an account that has hotels with partnerships (`@account.partnerships`), I get an empty [], whereas when I directly use the relevant hotel(`@hotel.partnerships`), I get my list of relevant partnerships.

Could you tell me why these associations dont work :

```
 has_many :partnerships, through: :hotels, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :partnerships, through: :offices, dependent: :destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `has_many :partnerships` is overriding the first.

```
has_many :partnerships, through: :hotels, dependent: :destroy # 1
has_many :partnerships, through: :offices, dependent: :destroy # 2
```

A way to get around this is to prefix the associations:

```
has_many :hotel_partnerships, through: :hotels, source: :partnerships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :office_partnerships, through: :offices, source: :partnerships, dependent: :destroy
```